# database setting instances from one table as properties to instances from another

Tags: database

I'm new to databases so this might be a stupid question with stupid wordings.

Consider a database table **Players** and another one, **Team**.
Instances from **Team** all have a property *players* which is an array consisting of the players in that particular team.

Is it then possible to automatically link those players to instances from the **Players** table? If I wanted to update a value for one of the **Players** instances, the linked player in the **Team** table would automatically update itself. This would be the desired behaviour. Is it possible?

For the record I'm using sqlite3 with node.js if that makes any difference. I would however regard this as a general database-related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a relational model these are called the KEYS.

One is a PRIMARY KEY to identify the Player and team instances, then that is used as a reference in the other table and called a FOREIGN KEY.

the table structure would look similar to this:

```
Team
-------------
team_id
name

Player
-----------
player_id
name
team_id
```

Or, if you want the same player to possibly be on multiple teams - then like this:

```
team
---------
team_id
name

player
---------
player_id
name

roster
-------------
team_id
player_id
```

then you query the structure to find the answer you want: e.g. which players are on team 1:
first design

```
SELECT * FROM player WHERE team_id = 1
```

second design

```
SELECT * FROM player p, roster r
WHERE r.team = 1
AND r.player_id = p.player_id
```